# Scala, spray-json: universal enumeration json formatting

Tags: json, scala, enums, spray-json

I have such model: two enumerations and one case class with two fields of these enums types:

```
// see later, why objects are implicit
implicit object Fruits extends Enumeration {
  val Apple = Value("apple")
  val Orange = Value("orange")
}

implicit object Vegetables extends Enumeration {
  val Potato = Value("potato")
  val Cucumber = Value("cucumber")
  val Tomato = Value("tomato")
}

type Fruit = Fruits.Value
type Vegetable = Vegetables.Value

case class Pair(fruit: Fruit, vegetable: Vegetable)
```

I want to parse/generate JSONs to/from Pairs with spray-json. I don't want to declare separate `JsonFormat`s for fruits and vegetables. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

// enum is implicit here, that's why we needed implicit objects
implicit def enumFormat[A <: Enumeration](implicit enum: A): RootJsonFormat[enum.Value] =
  new RootJsonFormat[enum.Value] {
    def read(value: JsValue): enum.Value = value match {
      case JsString(s) =>
        enum.withName(s)
      case x =>
        deserializationError("Expected JsString, but got " + x)
    }

    def write(obj: enum.Value) = JsString(obj.toString)
  }

// compilation error: couldn't find implicits for JF[Fruit] and JF[Vegetable]
implicit val pairFormat = jsonFormat2(Pair)

// expected value:
// spray.json.JsValue = {"fruit":"apple","vegetable":"potato"}
// but actually doesn't even compile
Pair(Fruits.Apple, Vegetables.Potato).toJson
```

Sadly, `enumFormat` doesn't produce implicit values for `jsonFormat2`. If I write manually two implicit declarations before pairFormat for fruits and vegetables formats, then json marshalling works:

```
implicit val fruitFormat: RootJsonFormat[Fruit] = enumFormat(Fruits)
implicit val vegetableFormat: RootJsonFormat[Vegetable] = enumFormat(Vegetables)

implicit val pairFormat = jsonFormat2(Pair)

// {"fruit":"apple","vegetable":"potato"}, as expected
Pair(Fruits.Apple, Vegetables.Potato).toJson
```

So, two questions:

1. How to get rid of these `fruitFormat` and `vegetableFormat` declarations?
2. Ideally it would be great to not make enumeration objects implicit, while keeping `enumFormat` function generic. Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe, using `scala.reflect` package or something like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to replace `enum.Value` with `A#Value`.

Looking at [spray-json #200](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/200) you can find an example of a well defined implicit `enumFormat`, slightly modified to leverage implicit `enu` retrieval:

```scala
implicit def enumFormat[T <: Enumeration](implicit enu: T): RootJsonFormat[T#Value] =
  new RootJsonFormat[T#Value] {
    def write(obj: T#Value): JsValue = JsString(obj.toString)
    def read(json: JsValue): T#Value = {
      json match {
        case JsString(txt) => enu.withName(txt)
        case somethingElse => throw DeserializationException(s"Expected a value from enum $enu instead of $somethingElse")
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Scala doesn't allow implicit chaining, because it would lead to combinatorial explosions that would make the compiler too slow.

See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html

> Scala does not allow two such implicit conversions taking place, however, so one cannot got from A to C using an implicit A to B and another implicit B to C.

You'll have to explicitly produce a `JsonFormat[T]` for each `T` you want to use.